# how to stop jetty without knowing the stop key

Tags: solr, jetty

when i ran jetty which is embedded with in apache solr. All i did was

java -jar start.jar

and it ran i put the process in the bg by doing ctrl-z and bg

i am trying to stop it by

java -DSTOP.PORT=8983 -DSTOP.KEY=stop_jetty -jar start.jar --stop

And i am not really sure if the the stop key above is correct . i get no error and go 
into a new prompt. the app is still listening at that port.

and when i did

java -DSTOP.PORT=8983 -jar start.jar --stop 
It said it requires the -DSTOP.KEY property as well.

I am not sure if i want to kill the process. Any tip/suggestion ? where to look for the stop key. i did not provide any keys at the start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the server was started without a STOP.KEY then you can't request a --stop.

Now, that being said, you can always issue a kill on the process too.

```
$ kill -TERM {pid of jetty}
```

Comment: "pgrep -f jetty" to get the pid